# How to perform checkBox_CheckedChanged event?

Tags: asp.net

Suppose there is CheckBox  and I want to perform checkBox_CheckedChanged event when it is checked.how to do that?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="checkBox_CheckedChanged" />
```

Code-behind:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

protected void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    bool @checked = checkBox.Checked;
    // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: sir,If i write 
bool @checked = checkBox.Checked; then error comes that checked is keyword identifier expected. This error come? So That code is not working

Comment: @Shalni: I guess that `bool checked` doesn't work because of syntax keyword but `bool @checked` where escaping took place - should work properly. Does it?

Comment: bool @checked is fine but checkBox.Checked is giving error.But I remove that error by using if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [AutoPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback.aspx) property to `true`.

Comment: What is the resion to make autoPostBack=true;Ya its working now but why its not working when autopostback =false;